# How to get CORS working on a hosting account?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess, cors

I have been trying to get CORS working on a free hosting account for sometime now but without success. I got it to work locally using a different port, but does not work when I upload the script into a remote server. I tried the PHP version of CORS:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}
?>
```

and .htaccess in my hosting account:

```
RewriteEngine On

<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
     <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
     </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Therefore is there a better way to get CORS to work in a remote server or the problem is with the hosting provider? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fire up something like fiddler and have a look what is actually going back and forth between server and client on http level.

Comment: Your `.htaccess` file looks good to handle CORS for php files, no need to add the code to the php script.. What kind of errors do you have ?

Comment: Thanks for replying Marvin and Pedro. Generally, these approaches should work! and they do work locally as I have setup an origin and destination that are of different domains using ports. But after uploading the same script online to a remote server, the client does not seem to gain access to it. Tried the .htaccess approach didn't work either. So I was wondering whether is the hosting provider blocking such requests or something else!

Comment: I'm thinking of trying with another provider and see if it will work.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.destination.com/ping.php?_dc=1429307688974. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:1841' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Comment: 403 is an error page, what's it say?

Comment: 403 is simply a HTTP status error when access to a particular resources is forbidden! @dandavis

Comment: well, that will stop cors, but the problem is "lower" than that, if you correct the forbidden, then cors will probably work. if you can't do OPTIONs, then you can only do a small subset of cors requests, to a php page.

Comment: But the thing that I don't understand is why I get the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" error while I have headers present in my php file!? It simply doesn't make any sense!